# How to find the corresponding IRQ to GPIO-Pin

Tags: debian, interrupt, irq

I am currently trying to get an extern Interrupt on my RockPro64 with RK3399 Processor working. So far I managed to activate the Pins accordingly but now when it comes to implementing the ISR I am stuck as I don't understand how I can get the Right IRQ number and thus don't know to which address to write my ISR to.

So far I activated GPIO1_A as an output, made it pulse and connected it to GPIO1_C6 which I configured as an interrupt. It seems that this setup is doing what I wanted it todo, as I get the right Register entries in the INT_STATUS and INT_RAWSTATUS registers. If in unmask the Interrupt I can experience a "lag" on my Board, but don't see any significant change in '/proc/interrupts'.

My plan was to get the right Address in the Vector Table and then write a minimalistic Function (the application only needs to set a flag) there according to this guide https://www.embedded.com/modeling-interrupt-vectors/

my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>


unsigned long strtadr=(0xFF730000); //startaddress for GPIO1

#define RegLength 64*1024UL
#define DDRos 0x0004
#define DRos 0x0000
#define INTenos 0x0030
#define INTPolos 0x003c
#define INTMaskos 0x0034
#define INTStatos 0x0040
#define INTRStatos 0x0044


void ResetGpio1(void *map, int fd, int unmap){

*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+DDRos) &= 0;
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+DRos) &= 0;
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTPolos)&=0;
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTMaskos)&= 0;
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTenos)&=0;
unmap=munmap(map,RegLength);
close(fd);

}


void SetGpio1(void *map){

*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+DRos)&=0; //set DR for all GPIO1s to 0; reset just to be sure
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+DDRos) |= 16; //set gpio1a4 to output DDR offset 0x0004, 1=output

}


void Gpio1IntEN(void *map){

*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTPolos)|=0x400000;
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTMaskos)&= 0;
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTenos)|=0x400000;
}



void ISR(void)__attribute__((interrupt("IRQ")));
void ISR(void){
printf("hello world");

}


int main(void) {
int unmap;
int fd;
void *map;

fd=open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR|O_SYNC);

    if(fd<0){
    printf("/dev/mem konnte nicht geÃ¶ffnet werden \n");
    return -1;  
    }

map=mmap(NULL, RegLength, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, strtadr);


SetGpio1(map);
Gpio1IntEN(map);

printf("INTstatus %X \n",*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTStatos));
printf("INTRstatus %X \n",*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTRStatos));



for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+DRos) |= 16;
printf("turning on \n");
printf("INTstatus %X \n",*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTStatos));
printf("INTRstatus %X \n",*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTRStatos));
sleep(1);

*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+DRos) &= ~16;
sleep(1);
printf("turned off \n");
printf("INTstatus %X \n",*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTStatos));
printf("INTRstatus %X \n",*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+INTRStatos));
}

/* *(volatile unsigned long *)(map+DDRos) &= 0;
*(volatile unsigned long *)(map+DRos) &= 0; */

ResetGpio1(map, fd, unmap);


}
```

the Datasheet for RK3399 can be found here: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1132005/ROCKCHIP/RK3399.html

I'm Working on Debian with GCC version 6.3.0